# Unable to read postgres array into a enum

Tags: go

Im trying to emulate enums with a const of type string, the problem im having is scanning the query result.

First when i try to run i get an error " pq: scanning to model.MuscleType is not implemented;  ". I implemented this function, but it didnt work. However, if i dont use a enum emulation, and just straight up use string, it works just fine.

Does anyone has a idea of how i could get this to work?

```
package model

type MuscleType string

const (
    Chest    MuscleType = "Chest"
    Shoulder            = "Shoulder"
    Back                = "Back"
    Legs                = "Legs"
    Triceps             = "Triceps"
    Biceps              = "Biceps"
)

// function the error was complaining about
func (m *MuscleType) Scan(value interface{}) error {
    if value == nil {
        *m = ""
        return nil
    }

//i tried tweaking between uint8 and string and neither worked.
    if stringValue, ok := value.(uint8); ok {
        *m = MuscleType(stringValue)
        return nil
    }

    return fmt.Errorf("Invalid type for MuscleType")
}

type Exercise struct {
    ID               int64         
    Name             string        
    Muscle           MuscleType   
    AssistantMuscles []MuscleType  
    Equipment        EquipmentType 
}

package repository

func (r *ExerciseRepository) SelectAllExercises() ([]*model.Exercise, error) {
    query := "SELECT * FROM exercises"

    rows, err := r.DB.Query(query)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var exercises []*model.Exercise
    for rows.Next() {
        var exercise model.Exercise
        if err := rows.Scan(&exercise.ID, &exercise.Name, &exercise.Muscle, pq.Array(&exercise.AssistantMuscles), &exercise.Equipment); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        exercises = append(exercises, &exercise)
    }

    return exercises, nil
}
```

UPDATE:
I managed to make it work by scanning manually, looks a bit off and verbose, but it works lol. probably there is a better way to do this.

```
    var exercises []*model.Exercise
    for rows.Next() {
        var exercise model.Exercise
        var assistantMuscle []string
        if err := rows.Scan(&exercise.ID, &exercise.Name, &exercise.Muscle, pq.Array(&assistantMuscle), &exercise.Equipment); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        exercise.AssistantMuscles = make([]model.MuscleType, len(assistantMuscle))
        for i, muscle := range assistantMuscle {
            exercise.AssistantMuscles[i] = model.MuscleType(muscle)
        }

        exercises = append(exercises, &exercise)
    }
```

Comment: The receiver is for `*MuscleType` but the error is for `model.MuscleType`.

Comment: Take a look at https://go.dev/play/p/LjQH1Jg6r8t for an example

Comment: `MuscleType` is the same as `model.MuscleType`, i forgot to add package context in my question.

Comment: Yes but the receiver isn't on `model.MuscleType`, it's on `*model.MuscleType`.  The `.` dot operator for calling methods will handle it automatically, but `sql` cannot.